# Can I force a C++11 lambda to return by reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

This does not compile since the **lambda** expression returns by value:

```
#include <iostream>

class Item
{
public:
    int& f(){return data_;}
private:
    int data_ = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Item item;
    auto lambda = [](Item& item){return item.f();};
    lambda(item) = 42;  // lambda(item) is a rvalue => compile time error 
    std::cout << item.f() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way around this? Can I force a lambda to return **by reference**?

Comment: Where did you learn about lambdas that only taught the shortened version? The full syntax includes not only a way to explicitly state the return type, but a place for `mutable`, exception specifications, attributes, and captures. I could see skipping over some of those when first teaching lambdas, but not the return type.

Comment: It was on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions. I stopped reading on "The return type is implicit". Turns out that the main article contains the full syntax though.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should specify the lambda return type to be `int&`. If you leave the return type off [and the lambda is of form `return expression;` it will automatically deduce the return type.

```
#include <iostream>

class Item
{
public:
    int& f(){return data_;}
private:
    int data_ = 0;
};

int main()
{
    Item item;
    auto lambda = [](Item& item) ->int& {return item.f();}; // Specify lambda return type
    lambda(item) = 42;
    std::cout << item.f() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++14 it is also allowed to write `auto&` in trailing return type which will be more simple in case if type of return value is complex

Comment: or `decltype(auto)`