# Is it possible to return an object of type T by reference from a lambda without using trailing return type syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, trailing-return-type

Given the following code snippet:

```
struct T {}; 

std::function<T&(T&)> f = [](T& obj) -> T& { return obj; };
```

I was wondering if it is possible to infer the correct lambda return type (i.e. `T&`) without using *trailing return type syntax*.

Obviously, if I remove `-> T&` then a compile-time error will occur in that the deduced type would be `T`.

Comment: No, for the same reason that `auto v = obj;` would deduce `v` as `T` and not `T&`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16789500/560648

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In C++14, you can use `[](T& obj) -> decltype(auto) { return obj; }`. In that case, the return type of `f` is deduced from the declared type of `obj` (i. e. `T&` in this case).

Comment: Good answer but, actually, in the C++11 case we can use the solution proposed by @chrizke. Do you agree with me?

Comment: @FdeF I agree that @chrizke's answer is probably the best solution for this particular case if you're restricted to C++11. In this case I'd however advise against deducing the lambda type with `auto`, since this slightly changes the lambda return type (see my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40977730/is-it-possible-to-return-an-object-of-type-t-by-reference-from-a-lambda-without/40978005#comment69322167_40983963)).

Comment: @jsp I agree with you when you pointed out that the return type is actually `std::reference_wrapper<T>` and not `T&`. Anyway, the `auto` keyword does not change the lambda return type in that it is used to infer the specific type of the lambda, which is called _closure type_. Probably you meant that when a lambda is assigned to a `std::function` whose target function type is `T&(T&)` then the appropriate return type is correctly obtained (assuming we used `std::ref` as above ).

Comment: @FdeF You're right, I shouldn't have said it "changes the lambda return type" but rather "changes the return type of `foo`".

Answer (score 22):

No, but in C++14 you could use `auto&` as the *trailing-return-type*. If it's typing you're worried about, and compiler upgrades don't worry you at all, then this mostly solves your problem.

Comment: I would mention for completeness that the standard says _the lambda return type is `auto`, which is replaced by the type specified by the trailing return type if provided and/or deduced from return statements_. Then [dcl.spec.auto](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto) does the rest.

Answer (score 11):

In C++11, you could use the function std::ref to achieve what you asked for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct T {
  int mI = 0;
};

int main() {
  std::function<T&(T&)> foo = [](T&t) { return std::ref(t); };

  T tObj;
  T & tRef = foo(tObj);

  tRef.mI = 42;

  std::cout<<tObj.mI<<"\n"; // Returns 42
  std::cout<<tRef.mI<<"\n"; // Returns 42

  return 0;
}
```

The function

```
template<class T>
std::reference_wrapper<T> std::ref(T& t)
```

returns a reference_wrapper object, which basically is an object holding a pointer. This reference wrapper can be implicitly converted to the corresponding reference, see [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

Furthermore, you could replace `std::function<T&(T&)>` by `auto`:

```
auto foo = [] (T& t) { return std::ref(t); };
```

Comment: Note though, that in the final code snippet (where `std::function<T&(T&)>` is replaced by `auto`), the return type of `foo` is `std::reference_wrapper<T>`, not `T&`. As you said, it's implicitly convertible but technically, it's a different function signature.